# how to return some images as json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, froala

im new in .net mvc5 and i want use froala editor 
in froala's option for load images you should retun your image's prometers as a jason file
look like :

```
 [
   {
    url: 'http://exmaple.com/images/photo1.jpg',
    thumb: "http://exmaple.com/thumbs/photo1.jpg",
    tag: 'flower'
  },
  {
     url: 'http://exmaple.com/images/photo2.jpg',
     thumb: "http://exmaple.com/thumbs/photo2.jpg",
     tag: 'sport'
   }
 ]
```

and i dont know how to get images from img folder and return them as json 
 
this is [froala doc](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#imageManagerLoadURL) for how change this  metod 
sorry my language is not good

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the [.NET SDK for Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/dotnet) which has built-in options for that: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/dotnet/image-manager. It should be something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace demo.Controllers
{
    public class FroalaApiController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult LoadImages()
        {
            string uploadPath = "/Public/";

            try
            {
                return Json(FroalaEditor.Image.List(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, uploadPath));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(e);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult DeleteImage()
        {
            try
            {
                FroalaEditor.Image.Delete("/Public/" + HttpContext.Request.Form["src"]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(e);
            }


            return Json(true);
        }
    }
}
```